# Summing Dates in Range Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table defined like so:

```
CREATE TABLE Items (
    Barcode     CHAR(50)    PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
    Location    CHAR(15)    ,
    ManufacturedAt  TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE,
    ShippedOutAt    TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE,
    ReceivedAt  TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE,
    SoldAt      TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE,
    DiscardedAt TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE,
);
```

I am trying to get a sum of each date field for a location over the last twelve months.
So example results I am trying to get:

```
Date  NumManu NumShip NumRece NumSold NumDisc
DEC   5       3       3       2       1
NOV   3       5       5       3       2
```

I am no sql expert by any means, but I am unsure of how to do this without doing 12 different sql queries (one for each month), or is that the only way? Thanks in advance!

Comment: you'd need a pivot query, since you're trying to turn column values into rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done with a single query with either sub-selects (and with [set-returning functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html)):

```
SELECT  lo, hi, to_char(lo, 'MON') Date,
        (SELECT count(*) FROM Items WHERE ManufacturedAt BETWEEN lo AND hi) NumManu,
        (SELECT count(*) FROM Items WHERE ShippedOutAt   BETWEEN lo AND hi) NumShip,
        (SELECT count(*) FROM Items WHERE ReceivedAt     BETWEEN lo AND hi) NumRece,
        (SELECT count(*) FROM Items WHERE SoldAt         BETWEEN lo AND hi) NumSold,
        (SELECT count(*) FROM Items WHERE DiscardedAt    BETWEEN lo AND hi) NumDisc
FROM    generate_series(current_timestamp, current_timestamp - interval '11 mon', interval '-1 mon') ts,
LATERAL (select date_trunc('month', ts)) lo(lo),
LATERAL (select lo + interval '1 mon')   hi(hi)
```

... or with multiple joins of the same table:

```
SELECT    lo, hi, to_char(lo, 'MON') Date,
          count(DISTINCT JManu) NumManu,
          count(DISTINCT JShip) NumShip,
          count(DISTINCT JRece) NumRece,
          count(DISTINCT JSold) NumSold,
          count(DISTINCT JDisc) NumDisc
FROM      generate_series(current_timestamp, current_timestamp - interval '11 mon', interval '-1 mon') ts,
LATERAL   (select date_trunc('month', ts)) lo(lo),
LATERAL   (select lo + interval '1 mon')   hi(hi)
LEFT JOIN Items JManu ON JManu.ManufacturedAt BETWEEN lo AND hi
LEFT JOIN Items JShip ON JShip.ShippedOutAt   BETWEEN lo AND hi
LEFT JOIN Items JRece ON JRece.ReceivedAt     BETWEEN lo AND hi
LEFT JOIN Items JSold ON JSold.SoldAt         BETWEEN lo AND hi
LEFT JOIN Items JDisc ON JDisc.DiscardedAt    BETWEEN lo AND hi
GROUP BY  lo, hi
```

Comment: This is awesome! Exactly what I was looking for! I try to avoid multiple round trips to the db if possible, and I learn more about SQL every day!

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing something but it seems as though you could just use COUNT and then either ORDER BY or GROUP BY month.

Although I see now that you are only keeping track of the month as actual dates, so you would have to perform some sort of logic check to get dates that are BETWEEN the start and end of each month.

I believe you would have to manually account for each month in the where clause if this is the case.